# Convolution of a multivariate Gaussian and multivariate exponential distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

I have derived the convolution for a multivariate Gaussian distribution with a multivariate exponential distribution. The aim is to get a multivariate extension to the univariate [exponentially-modified Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution).

Given data $\pmb X \in \mathrm{R}^{n \times d}$, the likelihood for this convolution would be $\pmb X|\theta, \Sigma, \lambda \sim \mathsf{multivariateEMG}\, (\theta, \Sigma, \lambda)$ where parameters $\theta$ is mean of the convolution including means from both the Gaussian and the Exponential, $\Sigma$ is the covariance of the convolution and $\lambda$ is the skew component coming from the Exponential distribution. The prior over the parameters are $\pmb \theta \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta^\prime,\Sigma^\prime),  \quad
\Sigma^{-1} \sim \mathit{Wish}( H^{\prime -1},\sigma^\prime),\quad  \lambda \sim \mathit{Jeffrey}(\lambda)$.

By having such a distribution in place, one can have the best of both worlds: retain skewness given by the exponential distribution whilst working alongside a Gaussian (i.e. using the mean and covariance). This will be a very helpful distribution provided we can estimate distributional parameters 'nicely'.

The joint posterior of this convolution is non conjugate making its integral intractable. Therefore, for inference, I plan to use the ‘[noise contrastive estimation](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/gutmann10a/gutmann10a.pdf)’ for parameter estimation used for unnormalised distributions.

My query would be is this the right approach or since this is a convolution, one could just include the extra terms coming from the Exponential distribution into the Bayesian inference thereby not needing to work out the convolution (sum) in $P(\pmb X|\theta, \Sigma, \lambda)$ necessary to determine the likelihood.

Any advice on this matter would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would ask that you edit your post to add $\LaTeX$ math, so the difference between measurables $X$ and parameters $\theta$ is clear. As an example of the concreteness I mean, I ask: do you mean to calculate the standard Bayesian posterior $P(\theta|data) = \int{P(X=data|\theta)P(\theta)}d\theta$ where $X|\theta \sim P(X|\theta) = N(\theta,\sigma^2)$ and $P(\theta) \sim exp(\lambda)$, so you also mean to introduce the hyperparameters $\lambda$ and $\sigma^2$, viz., you really want to find the conditional posterior $P(\theta | data,\lambda,\sigma^2)$?

Comment: $\int exp(-([\sum_i(x_i-\theta)^2)]/2\sigma^2)~ exp(-\lambda \theta)~ d\theta$ is perfectly tractable given $\sigma^2, \lambda$ and a few good sufficient statistics from your data. But the posterior $P(\theta|data)$ will not be exponential. You might consider a mixture of conjugate priors (normals) to mock-up an exponential-like prior as a workable shortcut. For more complicated problems, Gibbs sampling and/or Metropolis-Hastings MCMC are available for approximating posteriors.

Comment: @PeterLeopold: Thank you for the response and suggestions. I have edited my post placing links and Latex'd equations. Hope this clarifies the post further. Thank you indeed for your suggestions.